# As a native speaker, can I ask a parsing/meaning question?

Tags: support, english-language-and-usage, asking-questions

English is my first language, but I have encountered a text that I cannot parse. I can extract some meaning from it, but on closer inspection it doesn't actually seem to be formally correct. Can I ask about it on ELL? Or would ELU be better?

(It's not from *Ulysses* or anything along those lines...)

Answer (score 3):

I would say that questions on ELL should, in general, be of a sort that a person learning English might well ask, or a question such as might be of benefit to a person learning English. There is no rule that says a native speaker cannot ask a question. However, if thew question involves a technical point of usage of a sort not likely to be interesting or helpful to a person learning English, it might get better answers on ELU. It is not uncommon for a question to be migrated from ELU to ELL, or from  ELL TO ELU, so if a question is asked in the "wrong"  place, it is fairly easy to move it to the "right" place. So I wouldn't worry overmuch about which site to post on. But please don't post the same question to both at once.

Answer (score 2):

Anybody can ask questions here. I have asked a couple myself.

But a passage of text that a native speaker cannot interpret is probably not of use to anybody learning English. I don't know if your question is on-topic for ELU, but it's off-topic for ELL.